# How to make language change permanently?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a question. I read a post here about how to change the language by sending a parameter to the controller and the controller can then handle the change.

here is what I had read:

First: add route

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", 
"{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
new { language = "en", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Second: use ActionLink to send the parameter

```
<li><%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Spanish", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
    new { language = "es" })%></li>
<li><%= Html.ActionLink(
    "French", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
    new { language = "fr" })%></li>
<li><%= Html.ActionLink(
    "English", 
    ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
    new { language = "en" })%></li>
```

Now, I have tried this solution and it's working fine. However, it only works once. I mean, if you click on French, it will display the page in French. But the rest of the links on the page still point to the default "en".

How can I change the default "language" value to the selected language so that all links use the new language selected?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in your view? `es`=>`en`

Comment: Besides you could show the generated html after you choose "french"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the selection to be "remembered" then you will need to use an approach that stores the initial selection.

Your main options are therefore using a cookie or storing the selection in a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Using resource files seems to be the most effective way for this purpose. You need to store all texts to be displayed on the page in the resource file and you have to create separate resource files for all the languages you wish to support. Content on your page will be referred from a resource file based on language settings applied on the browser.

Following article on codeproject demonstrates it very well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/181738/Creating-a-Bilingual-ASP-NET-MVC3-Application-Part